# Copying data from multiple columns of source hive table to single column of target hive table in different rows

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have a requirement of copying data from one Hive source table to other target table. Below is source table structure with sample data:

```
source_table
Userid  Name    Phone1   Phone2  Phone3  Address1   Address2    Address3
123     Jitu    123456   987654  111111  DELHI      GURGAON     NOIDA       
234     Mark    123456   987654  111111  UK         USA         IND
```

While copying data from source to target, my requirement is to have Phone1, Phone2, Phone3 along with corresponding Address1, Address2 and Address3 
columns in a single column in target table. Below is how data should look like in target table:

```
Target_table
Userid  Name    Phone_no    Address
123     Jitu    123456      DELHI
123     Jitu    987654      GURGAON
123     Jitu    111111      NOIDA
234     Mark    123456      UK
234     Mark    987654      USA
234     Mark    111111      IND
```

I know simplest way to do this would be doing multiple inserts into target table for each Phone and address column from source table 
using either hive query language or spark dataframes.

Is there any other efficient method I can use to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case, if you are intrested in Hive solution as well,Lateral view yield cartesian product when joining multiple arrays result set.you can achieve the same results using posexplode as shown below:

```
select Userid,Name,phone,address
from source_table
lateral view posexplode(array(Phone1,Phone2,Phone3))  valphone as x,phone
lateral view posexplode(array(Address1,Address2,Address3)) valaddress as t,address
where x=t
;

hive> set hive.cli.print.header=true;

userid  name    phone   address
123     Jitu    123456  DELHI
123     Jitu    987654  GURGAON
123     Jitu    111111  NOIDA
234     Mark    123456  UK
234     Mark    987654  USA
234     Mark    111111  IND
Time taken: 2.759 seconds, Fetched: 6 row(s)
```

Answer (score 4):

Original dataframe can be selected several times, for each column index, and then selected dataframes combined into one by "union":

```
val df = Seq(
  (123, "Jitu", "123456", "987654", "111111", "DELHI", "GURGAON", "NOIDA"),
  (234, "Mark", "123456", "987654", "111111", "UK", "USA", "IND")
).toDF(
  "Userid", "Name", "Phone1", "Phone2", "Phone3", "Address1", "Address2", "Address3"
)

val columnIndexes = Seq(1, 2, 3)
val onlyOneIndexDfs = columnIndexes.map(idx =>
  df.select(
    $"Userid",
    $"Name",
    col(s"Phone$idx").alias("Phone_no"),
    col(s"Address$idx").alias("Address")))

val result = onlyOneIndexDfs.reduce(_ union _)
```

Output:

```
+------+----+--------+-------+
|Userid|Name|Phone_no|Address|
+------+----+--------+-------+
|123   |Jitu|123456  |DELHI  |
|123   |Jitu|111111  |NOIDA  |
|123   |Jitu|987654  |GURGAON|
|234   |Mark|123456  |UK     |
|234   |Mark|987654  |USA    |
|234   |Mark|111111  |IND    |
+------+----+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks pasha701, it works exactly how I needed it. And its quite optimized too as we are working with RDD directly.

Comment: @pasha701.. could you please post pyspark version as well?

Comment: sorry, I am not familiar with Python. In Scala $"Userid" means column "Userid". s"Phone$idx" means formatting, for ex. if  $idx=1, then "Phone1".